# Display JSON into html table c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am new to asp .net and doing some homeproject. Hope you can help! 
I have a ASP.NET Web API application with texbox that takes order number as serch string.

I find my object with this code:

```
var query = ReadFiles()
               .Where(n => n.orderNumber == TextBox1.Text)
               .Select(n => n);
```

After that Im trying to convert it to JSON witht his code:

```
var json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(query);
        TextBox1.Text = json;
```

I get a String back that says: JSON Visualizer

[image: JSON Visualizer]

Now for the question. How do I get this JSON string to the UI, I would like it to show up in some sort of table? I am new to asp .net with that in mind I hope this question is not to stupid. Oh and I use C#

Kind regards.

Comment: You can change your query `var query = ReadFiles().Where(n => n.orderNumber == TextBox1.Text).Select(n => n);` to `var query = ReadFiles().Where(n => n.orderNumber == TextBox1.Text);`. `Select` is unnecessary in your case.

Comment: Well are you using Razor or a JavaScript framework? I mean you can return that object from a Controller very easily.

Comment: JavaScript, but I am not really sure how I should do it. As I said I am new to this and I dont really know what/how I should do this. @Mark C.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Web API controller class, you can create a method endpoint that returns the data, and then use an Ajax request on the client to that end point.

This is a nice example: [Getting Started with ASP.NET Web API 2](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api). You should also look at [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) to understand the routing mechanism.

In your particular case, you could set up an endpoint to `post` the order number to from the client's text box (using Ajax). The controller method will then receive the order number as a parameter, and then fetch the data it needs on the server. You would then return the JSON response from that method. The client's success callback function from the `post` call will receive the JSON response, and then it's up to you to bind that to the markup with JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you ill have a look at that!